# Cheap Bulk Domain Registration

Tags: domains, domain-registration, multiple-domains

I have 6-7 domain names that I have thought of and I'm planning to buy it in bulk so that I can save.  Or am I wrong on this?

In my case, since its my first time to this hosting/domain registration, I only knew of GoDaddy with regards to domain registration.

Questions:

1. Will I lose out if I chose a cheap domain registrar compared to one that's popular?
2. For a newbie like me, what companies can you recommend for me to register domain names in bulk for cheap or affordable price?
3. I notice that some prices are higher because they offer support and customer service?  Aren't those servers not reliable at all?
4. I've heard of some domain registrars that they're increasing their prices every renewal?  Is that just natural in a business sense for these domain registrars?

Before posting this, I've been reading about NameCheap.com, and I'm considering registering for them unless you have other good choices to give me.

I'll appreciate every suggestion or advice you can give.

Comment: One of the things you definitely need to look out for is if the host/registrar has any fee on domain transfer. You might be not happy with their hosting, and some could charge over $20 for domain transfers. On 6-7 domains that would be $120-140 just to retain your domain.

Comment: Check if they charge for domain transfer, noted. For 6-7 domains that for $20 each?  Isn't that too much?  GoDaddy is between 12-14 dollars if I'm not mistaken.  Namecheap.com is even lesser.  I'll try to search for more.

Comment: Yes, it is too much indeed. I had this problem not long ago with a cheap hosting company: they want £15 for each domain to transfer. Since I never used that domain and the name was not valuable, I was better off buying another domain. However I did waste the initial £8 that they charged for the domain. I had better experiences with other companies, which can do this service free of charge. In my case it was not a big deal, but when you are dealing with more domains it could get expensive.

Comment: "6-7 domain names ... buy it in bulk so that I can save." Are 6-7 domains enough to "buy in bulk"? The registrars I've dealt with generally have bulk savings starting at 10 domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **1. Will I lose out if I chose a cheap domain registrar compared to one that's popular?**

I think it's SAFER to use "http://www.networksolutions.com/" because they are very reliable, and offer great protection both in the WHOIS and transfer departments. Though a contract is a contract ... is a contract. So if you purchase a domain for a period of time, if you are in compliance with the registrar's terms, they are obligated to let you have the domain for the period specified.

> **2. For a newbie like me, what companies can you recommend for me to register domain names in bulk for cheap or affordable price?**

Now if you're looking for **cheap** then you're best off looking for coupon codes online for various providers like NameCheap or GoDaddy or NetworkSolutions. (There are also third-party resellers like FatCow and MediaTemple to name a few). It all changes day-to-day.

> **3. I notice that some prices are higher because they offer support and customer service? Aren't those servers not reliable at all?**

I'm not sure where you heard that they're not reliable. Maybe hosting-wise. I think it's better to stick with a company offering **domains only** if you have your own servers, but if you're new to this, maybe a **reseller/host** is the better option for you. Customer support is a MUST and you should try to avoid any companies with a bad support reputation.

> **4. I've heard of some domain registrars that they're increasing their prices every renewal? Is that just natural in a business sense for these domain registrars?**

Every company does this. They keep prices low on new domains and transfers to sucker you in to using their service, and then charge "normal" rates after it's time to renew. You can avoid this or even get really REALLY good deals, by again, using coupons (30% off orders of $75 or more type of thing) and then buy extended leases, for 5-10 year periods. It will cost a great deal up front, but rather than renew every year for that same time, you could save up to 75% off.

I can say that MediaTemple has VERY good customer care and simple hosting, but they are very expensive for what you get ($20/mo for basic package of domain/hosting). If you're willing to take a few steps out of your comfort zone, I'd recommend using a specialized domain registrar, and then hosting it elsewhere.

And regarding buying in bulk: GoDaddy is the only company I've ever purchased from in bulk, but I'm positive almost all others will provide comparable discounts.

Comment: Do you think I should go with both hosting and domain on the same company or should I go with one for hosting and different for the domain register?  I'm considering the latter as I think I can save on it (or I maybe wrong again on this).

Comment: @Panoy - It depends what you're more comfortable with -- convenience comes with a greater cost but less flexibility usually. What are your intentions, so I can better help you?

Comment: I'm just quite intrigued about the difference if you just chose one company as both your host and domain provider.  Why do you say less flexibility if I choose to to both (host & domain) on one company? I'm just the inquisitive type.

Comment: @Panoy - I'll try to keep it short: As a "both" company, GoDaddy offers domains and hosting. Hosting is "not the fastest" and "not the cheapest" and the domains are "not the most secure" but it is simpler to manage hosting and domains in one place. If you're like me, you use Cloudflare (DNS host ONLY) with excellent everything. (You set the domain's name servers to Cloudflare where you register it). But by security in the WHOIS department I mean, "what information is publicly available about you?" and only your domain REGISTRAR can protect that. NetworkSolutions specializes in such.

Comment: @Panoy - I mean transfers, as in "can people snatch your domain without your permission if your domain isn't locked explicitly?" and "what about if I don't renew my domain -- how long is the grace period before it goes on the auction block again?" These are all things to consider.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4702/discussion-between-panoy-and-ionfish)